# 404 script not found with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack

I am fairly new to using Javascript with Node.Js. I am currently running an app that is based on OpenMCT(https://github.com/nasa/openmct) and I am having trouble with integrating a script to be used as a plugin inside an index.html file. When I start the Node.js server with npm start I'm seeing that when I inspect that my file has not been found (404 error with the telemetry.js file). Here is my setup for the index.html file and the attached script (both are found in the same directory).

index.html :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title></title>
        <script src="dist/openmct.js"></script>
        <script src="telemetry.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="dist/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="dist/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="dist/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        const FIVE_MINUTES = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        const THIRTY_MINUTES = 30 * 60 * 1000;

        [
            'example/eventGenerator'
        ].forEach(
            openmct.legacyRegistry.enable.bind(openmct.legacyRegistry)
        );

        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.Espresso());
        openmct.install(telemetry());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.MyItems());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.LocalStorage());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.Generator());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.ExampleImagery());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.UTCTimeSystem());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.AutoflowView({
            type: "telemetry.panel"
        }));
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.DisplayLayout({
            showAsView: ['summary-widget', 'example.imagery']
        }));
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.Conductor({
            menuOptions: [
                {
                    name: "Fixed",
                    timeSystem: 'utc',
                    bounds: {
                        start: Date.now() - THIRTY_MINUTES,
                        end: Date.now()
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: "Realtime",
                    timeSystem: 'utc',
                    clock: 'local',
                    clockOffsets: {
                        start: - THIRTY_MINUTES,
                        end: FIVE_MINUTES
                    }
                }
            ]
        }));
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.SummaryWidget());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.Notebook());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.LADTable());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.Filters(['table', 'telemetry.plot.overlay']));
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.ObjectMigration());
        openmct.install(openmct.plugins.ClearData(['table', 'telemetry.plot.overlay', 'telemetry.plot.stacked']));
        openmct.install(telemetry());
        openmct.start();
    </script>
</html>
```

telemetry.js:

```
function telemetry() {
    return function install() {
        console.log("I've been installed!");
    }
};
```

[image: Directory listing]

Here is the webpack configuration:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const packageDefinition = require('./package.json');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
// TODO: Build Constants w/ git-rev-sync
const gitRevision = require('child_process')
    .execSync('git rev-parse HEAD')
    .toString().trim();
const gitBranch = require('child_process')
    .execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD')
    .toString().trim();

const webpackConfig = {
    mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: {
        openmct: './openmct.js',
        espressoTheme: './src/plugins/themes/espresso-theme.scss',
        snowTheme: './src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss',
        maelstromTheme: './src/plugins/themes/maelstrom-theme.scss'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.join(__dirname, "src"),
            "legacyRegistry": path.join(__dirname, "src/legacyRegistry"),
            "saveAs": "file-saver",
            "csv": "comma-separated-values",
            "EventEmitter": "eventemitter3",
            "bourbon": "bourbon.scss",
            "vue": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"),
            "d3-scale": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/d3-scale/build/d3-scale.min.js"),
            "printj": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/printj/dist/printj.min.js"),
            "styles": path.join(__dirname, "src/styles"),
            "MCT": path.join(__dirname, "src/MCT"),
            "testTools": path.join(__dirname, "src/testTools.js")
        }
    },
    devtool: devMode ? 'eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __OPENMCT_VERSION__: `'${packageDefinition.version}'`,
            __OPENMCT_BUILD_DATE__: `'${new Date()}'`,
            __OPENMCT_REVISION__: `'${gitRevision}'`,
            __OPENMCT_BUILD_BRANCH__: `'${gitBranch}'`,
            __OPENMCT_ROOT_RELATIVE__: `'${devMode ? 'dist/' : ''}'`
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[name].css'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: 'src/images/favicons',
                to: 'favicons'
            },
            {
                from: './index.html',
                transform: function (content) {
                    return content.toString().replace(/dist\//g, '');
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sc|sa|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'fast-sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /zepto/,
                use: [
                    "imports-loader?this=>window",
                    "exports-loader?Zepto"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|ico|woff2?|eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath(url, resourcePath, context) {
                        if (/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/.test(url)) {
                            return `images/${url}`
                        }
                        if (/\.ico$/.test(url)) {
                            return `icons/${url}`
                        }
                        if (/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf)$/.test(url)) {
                            return `fonts/${url}`
                        } else {
                            return `${url}`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        modules: false,
        timings: true,
        colors: true,
        warningsFilter: /asset size limit/g
    }
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Comment: Which file is returning the 404 status?

Comment: FYI, `<script>` tags should go **inside** the `<head>` or `<body>` sections. Yours is outside

Comment: The telemetry.js is returning the 404 error. I followed the same procedure highlighted in their tutorials for the inclusion of the file (https://github.com/nasa/openmct-tutorial) which worked with that version of the code and for some reason is not working with this one...

Comment: Double-check that your `telemetry.js` file actually exists, matches that filename exactly (same case, no leading or trailing whitespace, etc) and is in the root folder next to `index.html`

Comment: Doubled-checked still gives me the same error. If I remove this script the page behaves normally and loads everything else correctly. I'm really wondering if it's something with my configuration but I'm having the same problem with my macOS Catalina and Ubuntu 18.04 so most likely a code error.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot of your app's directory?

Comment: See the edited original post for the app directory screenshot.

Comment: That doesn't look much like the [tutorial app](https://github.com/nasa/openmct-tutorial). How does your _server_ work? I see you've got a Webpack config, how is Webpack configured?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213056/discussion-between-demz-and-phil).

Comment: Include `telemetry.js` in your `CopyWebpackPlugin` config

Comment: @Phil updated the comment in the chat room for my webpack config !

Answer (score 0):

Got an update and fix from the official GitHub repo :

> The problem in this case is that our build and development environment is not aware of your new plugin. For building Open MCT we use Webpack, only knows about source files if they are part of the dependency tree that starts with the source code entry point, in this case openmct.js. Because your plugin is not included from any of our source code, Webpack doesn't know about it, so it does not get served by the Webpack dev server.

https://github.com/nasa/openmct/issues/2954